# C# Value and Reference types

Tags: c#, value-type, reference-type

Please see the following lines of code mentioned below:

```
byte[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
byte[] b = a; // b will have all values of a.
a = null;
```

In C# `byte[]` is a reference type. Now if `a = null` in line 3, then why `b` is not null since its a reference type. If we check `b` it will still have all values of `a`.

Comment: because you set null reference to the `a` while `b` is still referencing byte array

Comment: it's the difference between a variable and a value. b is a variable which holds a reference to a certain value. changing the reference does not change the value.

Comment: byte[] is a value type not reference type

Comment: @EhsanSajjad `byte[]` is a **reference** type

Comment: any reference link @SriramSakthivel

Comment: byte is value type, but all arrays are reference types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301755.aspx - 1st paragraph

Comment: `Note that every array is a reference type`, even if its members are value types. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx

Comment: elaborate please @HassanNisar

Comment: because if b is null then u got a null value

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Just look at the documentation for [Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array) and note that it is a `public abstract class`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad. Array types are reference types derived from the abstract base type Array. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9b9dty7d.aspx

Answer (score 7):

First you create an array somewhere in the memory, for example starting at address `1000`. `a` is a reference, it does not contain the array, it contains the address `1000`. `b` also contains this address. In line 3 you change `a` to point to `null` instead, but `b` is still pointing at the array in address `1000`.

You edited the reference (`a`), you did not edit the object it referenced to (`{1,2,3,4}`).

Answer (score 7):

That's actually how [reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) works.

As you said, `byte[]` is a reference type **like all other arrays**. Let's analyze your sample line by line;

```
byte[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

--> You created a byte array in memory and `a` is a reference that array.

[image]

```
byte[] b = a;
```

--> Your `b` is referencing the same object with `a` which is `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` but **they are different references**.

[image]

```
a = null;
```

--> Your `a` is not referencing anywhere in the memory but that doesn't effect `b`.

[image]

Comment: I know I know.. I'm terrible at paint.

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes the assumption that when you make the assignment:

```
byte[] b = a;
```

And that you're making some sort of graph association like so:

```
b -> a -> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
```

And when you make the assignment of `a` to `null`, you impact the value of `b`, because:

```
b -> a -> null
```

But that's not how copying references work.  When you copy the reference, you really make a *copy* of the reference that `a` has, like so:

`a ----> { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
              ^
b ------------|`

This is why when you make the assignment of `a` to `null`, you don't impact the value of `b`, just `a`:

`a ----> null      { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
                          ^
b ------------------------|`

Answer (score 0):

You are making `b` point to the memory address that contains the `byte` array. Then *afterwards*, you are making `a` point to `null`. `b` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

A reference type variable points to a value. When you assign one ref type variable to another you copy reference to its value not to the variable itself. This is why `b` still points to a table of values.

Answer (score 0):

When a type is a value type, it means that the variables of this type store the actual data. When a type is a reference type, it means that the variables of this type store a reference to the actual data.

In both cases, assignment from one variable to another *copies* the content of the variable. For value types, this means that the value is copied from one variable to the other, duplicating the actual data and thus creating a new object. For reference types, this means that *the reference is copied* from one variable to the other, duplicating the reference but leaving the actual data intact. To stress that: the object isn't copied, but *the reference is*. The two copies of the reference are independent, even though it's easy to observe that they point to the same object when dereferenced.

From these you can easily see that the assignment from one variable to the other copies the reference to the byte array, so you have two references to the byte array. Afterwards, when you assign null to one of the variables, you are copying a null reference to it, overwriting the original reference (which was stored in that variable) to the byte array. So, now you don't have two references to the byte array, but only one again - the object is the same, but the references to it are independent.

(Similarly, if you reassign the byte array back to the nulled variable, it doesn't mean that *all* variables in your program that pointed to null will point to the byte array - only the one you assigned will.)